# Value is not binding to Array first index in AngularJs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, binding, mapping

Value binding is not working ,in this case im going to map one value to array first index which is in loop  `key1.MappingOption` which i want to map to array which is `key1.MappingOptionsColumns[0]`

```
   if (key1.IsMultiSelect) {
    key1.MappingOptionsColumns = [];
    key1.MappingOptionsColumns[0] = key1.MappingOptions;
    if (key1.FieldTypeEnum == 17) {
        key1.MappingOptionsColumns[0] = key1.MappingOptions.toString();
        console.log("key1.MappingOptionsColumns", key1.MappingOptionsColumns[0]);
        console.log("key1", key1);
    }
}
```

after that im getting 
[console value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1A0T.png)

Comment: This is not a binding issue and doesn't have anything to do with AngularJs. Would you be able to provide a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) for this?

Comment: i dont have plunker for this because it is huge code but mostly this part of code is responsible for that

Comment: Where is the angularjs code, that you are assigning `key1.MappingOptionsColumns` to `$scope` or `vm / this` ?

Comment: no..this is final code we could not identified what is the issue